# Convert server time zone to local time zone in Crystal Reports

Tags: crystal-reports, timezone, utc

I have a time field (LaborHed.ClockInTime) that in Epicor server (the ERP I'm using) has 1 hour difference from my local time. My local time zone is UTC (Dublin, Edinburgh, Lisbon, London). I don't know how to convert the Epicor server time zone to my local time zone.

I tried this code (but it doesn't work)

> ShiftDateTime (cdate({BAQReportResult.LaborHed.ClockInTime}),"UTC,0",
>   "")

What I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

If it's for a print field, increase the hour in the formula. Otherwise, this will use the current user time zone:

```
ShiftDateTime ( CurrentDateTime, PrintTimeZone, CurrentCEUserTimeZone)
```

To enforce a timezone, such as British summer time, use the following:

```
ShiftDateTime (cdate({BAQReportResult.LaborHed.ClockInTime}),"UTC,0, BST", "")
```

Answer (score 1):

### See reference to ShiftDateTime in Crystal Reports Online Help

```
ShiftDateTime (inputDateTime, inputTimeZone, newTimeZone)
```

---

> Epicor server (the ERP I'm using) has 1 hour difference from my local time. My local time zone is UTC (Dublin, Edinburgh, Lisbon, London).
>
> What I'm doing wrong?

**You need to input the server time zone.**

It looks as though `ShiftDateTime (cdate({BAQReportResult.LaborHed.ClockInTime}),"UTC,0", "")` ***inputs and outputs*** your local time.

---

> how to convert the Epicor server time zone to my local time zone.

Since your local time is UTC/London, I'm assuming server time is UTC+1.  Crystal Reports syntax for ***inputTimeZone*** and ***newTimeZone*** is "std,offset".

- std = String name of the standard time zone.
- offset = Offset, in minutes, of the standard time zone (west is positive).

**Try this**:

```
ShiftDateTime (cdate({BAQReportResult.LaborHed.ClockInTime}), "UTC,-60", "")
```

***or write local time zone explicitly like this:***

```
ShiftDateTime (cdate({BAQReportResult.LaborHed.ClockInTime}), "UTC,-60", "UTC,0")
```